# Troubleshooting Discord.js v14 Embed: GIF not loading properly in Slash Command Hug

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have been trying to make a hug slash command for my discord bot and this gif is not loading in embed. It is working properly without embed but i need it in embed.

````
const{api_id}=require('../utility/id.json')
module.exports={
  data:new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('hug').setDescription('hug someone')
  .addUserOption(op => op.setName('who').setDescription('who do you want to hug?').setRequired(true)),
  category:'fun',
  async execute(interaction){
    //gif
    const result = await fetch(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=${api_id}&q=anime+hug&limit=20&offset=3&rating=pg&lang=en`).catch(er => console.log(er));
    const result_json = await result.json(); 
   const index =  Math.floor(Math.random() * result_json.data.length)
  const gif = await result_json.data[index].url;
const member = interaction.options.getMember('who');
const message =`${interaction.user} hugs ${member}` ;
try{
const myEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
.setColor(0xf5f542)
.setImage(gif)
.setTimestamp()
await interaction.reply({content:message, embeds: [myEmbed]});
await interaction.channel.send(gif)
}catch(err){
    interaction.channel.send('error loading gif')
    console.log(err)
  }
  },
} ```
````

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but you have unnecessary `await` statements in multiple places, see [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) and how they are used with [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: There's only one place where `await` is not needed, which is in the definition for `gif`. Every other use of `await`  is fine

Comment: Can you log `gif` and include an example of the url?

Comment: @Elitezen thanks.
and yes i can include an example of the url. It is working fine but It's not loading when i'm using it in embed.